# How to connect to a computer that is in Sleep mode over the internet

Tags: wake-on-lan, remote-desktop

How to connect to a computer that is in Sleep mode over the internet?

I am using LogMeIn to connect to another computer offsite. I just installed Windows 7 RC on that system and found that the Sleep mode actually works. Currently LogMeIn does not connect when the system is in Sleep mode or Hibernate mode (that is what their error message displays when you try).

Is there a way to get LogMeIn to connect to a system in Sleep mode?
Is there other software that gives simliar LogMeIn functionallity (like RDP, etc.) that could be used on Windows 7 instead. I just use LMI for connecting and nothing else (no printing or file transfers). A Non-expensive options (such as free) would be better.

I have seen web sites mentioning "Wake on LAN". Does anyone have some good links on how to set this up to be accessed over the internet?

Edited:
It looks like LogMeIn BETA might be the solution.

https://beta.logmein.com/welcome/nextgen/

Has anyone tried this beta yet?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be having WOL capable device in network, for example DD-WRT router, that could be used to wake up your PC. Unfortunantly WOL doesn't work over routers.

Comment: Any chance you can port forward the WOL packet?  It's a broadcast message so I assume not.

Comment: No you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link where to find information and free tools about WOL.

http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/

If you don't control your closest router to enable "Subnet Directed Broadcasts" you get get one quite cheap and setup a NAT/firewall too.